# Assigned the key to variable and pass variable as key in vbs

Tags: vbscript

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell, intRetVal, intErrNum
Dim sn As String
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run("c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")
WScript.Sleep 2000

sn = f

If objShell.AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad") Then
   WScript.Sleep 500
   objShell.SendKeys "%{sn}"

End If
```

In the above vbs code I am trying to pass alt+f Key to "untitled - Notepad" application but instead of passing key directly I wanted to assigned it to some variable and then pass the variable.

But above code is throwing below error while executing the script,

E:\vbs\test2.vbs(3, 8) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expec
ted end of statement

How should I assigned the key to variable and pass variable as key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 mistakes in your script:

1. `Dim sn As String`

   As [Adrien Lacroix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501778/1630171) already pointed out, VBScript doesn't support typed variable declarations as VBA does. Change that line into this:

   ```
   Dim sn
   ```
2. `sn = f`

   You want to assign the character `f` to the variable `sn`, so you have to make the former an actual string by putting it between double quotes:

   ```
   sn = "f"
   ```
3. `objShell.SendKeys "%{sn}"`

   VBScript doesn't support variable expansion inside strings. If you want to build a strings with values from variables you have to concatenate the variable with the string literals. Also, the curly braces are for generating special keystrokes (e.g. `{Right}` for <kbd>→</kbd> or `{F10}` for <kbd>F10</kbd>), not for variable expansion. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83) for details. To send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> you need the following:

   ```
   objShell.SendKeys "%" & sn
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is on this line (*E:\vbs\test2.vbs(3, 8)*) :

```
sn = f
```

provoked by this one :

```
Dim sn As String
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) :
"*In VBScript, variables are always of one fundamental data type, Variant*"

VBScript does not support data types as such so remove all data types from your declarations. 
For example, that line should be just:

`Dim sn`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the above solution but now its opening the notepad application but does not pass the alt+f key. Got the below error while passing the key, " E:\vbs\test2.vbs(15, 4) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument "